# Change UIButton attributes for particular state when no dedicated method available

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

`UIButton` provides several methods for changing appearance for particular state, e.g.

```
UIButton setTitle:(NSString *) forState:(UIControlState)
```

but what to do when there is no dedicated method?

for example I want to change center or frame of button image or label:

```
button.titleLabel.frame = CGRect(...)
```

The frame of label changes. But when user taps the button layout glitches because frames for other states had not been changed.

Is there any way better than handling all events and setting attributes in handler method?

Frame of the label is just an *example* - it could be many other things like background color of text label.

Comment: you may be use uipangesture for solve this.. :)